# Setting up GNSDK development environment - nmake doesn't work

Tags: c, makefile, gracenote

I'm following [GNSDK: The Barebones C Intro](https://developer.gracenote.com/gnsdk-barebones-c-intro) and have a problem while setting up the development environment.

The instructions say:

*The first thing you need to do is set up your development environment. I coded and ran this application on Windows System 7. The SDK comes with a number of C samples. Each sample has its own folder. For this application, I cloned one of the folders and named it "/Samples/gnsdk_barebones". I used the "makefile" in the cloned directory and the Visual Studio 2008 C/C++ compiler to run the makefile from the command line (Visual Studio 2008 > Tools > Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt). It's important that you create your folder under /Samples as the makefile uses relative path names to do its build.*

I'm running MSVS 2015 on MS-Windows10 laptop.

I opened the 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2015' and type the following command

C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Play\GNSDK\samples\gnsdk_barebones>nmake -f makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23918.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

makefile(8) : fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation
Stop.

The gnsdk_barebones folder contains two files that were downloaded as part of the SDK.

1. main.c
2. makefile

I couldn't find any record makefile(8) error type and would appreciate your advice.

Please let me know if further info is required.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `makefile(8)` means the error is at line 8 of the makefile.

Comment: @mike
    Much obliged! Now I understand why I couldn't find the exact error.
Line 8 on the makefile looks like this:

    _ifeq ($(filter static, $(MAKECMDGOALS)), static)_

I looked for references and it seems that ifeq receives only 2 arguments while there're 3 arguments in the statement above.

This issue is duplicated in some of Gracenote's SDK samples so how should they be used? Is there any validated project to be used in order to  learn how to use their fingerprinting service?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In the light of your comments, the explanation of your problem is that your makefile is
a makefile for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) - which is the make-
tool almost always used - and you are trying to run it with Microsoft's
make-tool, `nmake`, which is almost forgotten and cannot parse a GNU makefile.

You can get [GNU make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)
as a standalone package, or install it as part of a complete GNU GCC toolchain
for Windows such as [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/).

Your comments pose additional questions. It's one question at a time on
Stackoverflow :) See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).